# What are the differences between weapons of the same type in Fortnite Battle Royale?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

In Fortnite Battle Royale, there are different classes of weapons such as SMG, AR, Shotguns, Sniper rifles, etc. I understand the difference between these classes of weapons, but I don't understand the differences of weapons within each class. For example there are normal SMG's and Tactical SMG's. What are the differences between these guns regarding strength, range and other statistics?

Other examples would be, SCAR vs Assault Rifle (AR), Tactical Shotgun vs Pump shotgun vs Heavy Shotgun.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, Advanced versions of weapons (SCAR, suppressed Pistol, Tactical SMG, and Heavy Shotgun) are better stats wise, but its totally personal preference as to which one you use

#### Shotguns

Tactical shotguns shoot faster and do less damage than pump shotguns, and hold 8 shells as opposed to 5.

The Pump also takes a full second to pull out, while the tactical takes the standard half second.

The Heavy shotgun does damage comparable to the tactical, but allows for more range, which is both an advantage and a disadvantage, depending on the situation.

#### SMGs

Tactical smgs hold 5 more shots than suppressed SMGs, and do more damage, but are louder, making it easier to be found while shooting.

#### Pistols

The only difference between suppressed and normal pistols is damage and rarity.

#### Assault Rifles

The same as Pistols - damage and rarity are the only differences between SCAR and AR.

Comment: A little bit hard to read, but it will do

Comment: This answer is very incomplete: it doesn't mention Revolvers or Hand Cannons, Scoped Assault Rifles or Burst Assault Rifles, or Sniper Rifles at all which at least have the Hunting Rifle, Bolt-Action Rifle, and Semi-Automatic Rifle variants.

Comment: Suppressed pistols make much less sound too

Comment: Nice, now the question is clear

Comment: Don't forget about recoil.  Suppressed weapons don't recoil as much, so they're easier to stay on target while firing.  This is why I tend to avoid anything too heavy, like the gattling gun.

Comment: This is a late request, but now they added the new burst AR's. You also forgot the old ones

Comment: I edited the answer explaining every other type of gun in fortnite